# Changing Struct or Class inside a Class | with or without pointers

Tags: c++, class, parsing, struct

Changing values of classes/structs inside classes are a mystery to me. I tried to do some research today and came up with the following solution. I wonder if this is a proper way for a function to change stuff inside the class. Is there a need to for this to be somehow done with pointers? Is there a more proper way to accomplish this?

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

class Someclass {
    private:
    int Integer;

    public:

    Someclass(int i):
    Integer(i){} //CTOR

    struct Somestruct { 
        int a, b;
    };
    Somestruct Mystruct;

    void func(){
        Mystruct.a = Integer/2;
        Mystruct.b = Integer*2;
    };
};

Someclass A(10);
A.func();
std::cout << A.Mystruct.a << " " << A.Mystruct.b << std::endl;
}
```

The reason I am writing this code, is because I want to parse a file, starting from the line "Integer" into a customly defined struct "Mystruct" which this class should somehow deliver me. Is this an acceptable way to write such a code?

Comment: I can't understand the problem. Why do you need inner class? Please, provide an example.

Comment: The data that needs to be parsed is huge ~contains around 30 different element values for each instance of Someclass (where the instances are set through "Integer") . I didn't want to write all the declarations/definitions in this class file so I wrote another header and cpp file that contains the struct definition and I will write the function somewhere else that parses the file. Just so that the code is more readable.

Comment: What does mean "instances are set through "Integer""?

Comment: I create a class with the constructor by setting the Integer. The parser finds the place in the text file depending on the Integer and extracts around 30 attributes. Every time something needs to be extracted I create a class with constructor Integer, get the values, and then destruct my class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that your question is about encapsulation, being understood that the inner struct is a data holder and the outer class has to manage it somehow.

**Weaknesses of your design**

In your design, `Mystruct` is public.  So anything outside `Someclass` could access the data, but also change it.  This is error prone, as there is no guarantee that the outside code doesn't break some invariant of the structure.

**Ways for improvement**

The cleanest thing would certainly to make some getters and setters to access the data.  But with 30 members, it's a lot of code.

If your construction process initialises the struture's data, a second approach could be to limit outside access to read-only.  You'd do that by making `Mystruct` private and offering a function returning a const reference:

```
class Someclass {
    Somestruct Mystruct; 
public: 
    ...
    const Somestruct& get() { return Mystruct; }
};

std::cout << A.get().a << " " << A.get().b << std::endl;
```

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/3Ch5OX)

Nevertheless before going into that direction, I'd check if access to the structure's raw data couldn't be encapsulated, for example by providing functions that manage the data without need to know the internals:

```
class Somestruct {
    ...
public:
    ostream& show_simplified_specs(ostream& os) {
        os << a << " " << b;
    }
}
```

A third approach could be to use the [builder design pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/builder-pattern.html) to encapsulate the construction process of a `Someclass` based on `Somestruct` and other parts.

**Pointers ?**

Pointers should be avoided if possible. For example, suppose you have a vector of `Someclass` to keep all these classes in memory. At a moment in time, you get a pointer to an element's `Mystruct`.  Suppose you'd then add a new item to the vector: all the previous pointers might get invalidated.

This same risk potentially exist with references.  But I think that while it's a common idiom to cache a pointer returned by a function,in practice it's less common and appealing to copy a reference returned by a function.

Comment: Your understanding is on point. Thank you for the comment, which I find super instructive. I will go for the second approach you mention and try to initialize everything leaving Mystruct read-only.  Thanks again. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for? I'm not much confident I understood you right.

```
template <int I>
struct Someclass;

template <>
struct Someclass<1>
{
    int Integer = 1;
    int a, b;

    void func()
    {
        a = Integer/2;
        b = Integer*2;
    }
};

template <>
struct Someclass<2>
{
    int Integer = 2;
    int a, b, c;

    void func()
    {
        a = Integer/2;
        b = Integer*2;
        c = Integer*Integer;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Someclass<1> A;
    A.func();
    std::cout << A.a << " " << A.b << std::endl;

    Someclass<2> B;
    B.func();
    std::cout << B.a << " " << B.b << " " << B.c << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```